# NSToolbar redo and undo auto - enable NSToolbarItem

Tags: cocoa, nsundomanager, nstoolbar, nstoolbaritem

In my document based application i implemented the redo and undo behavior with `NSUndoManager`.

**I want to enable or disable the undo / redo `NSToolbarItems` automatically (as in the default menu)**, based on the `canRedo` and `canUndo` (my `NSToolbarItems` are not imaged based, so `- (BOOL)validateToolbarItem:(NSToolbarItem *)theItem` is not called)

1) i tried binding the enable value to `self(My WC).document.undoManager.canUndo / self(My WC).document.undoManager.canRedo`

does not work, as canUndo and canRedo are not variable based, but just methods

2) i did add two properties to my WC canUndo and canRedo, which i modify on hand of `name:NSUndoManagerDidUndoChangeNotification` and `name:NSUndoManagerDidRedoChangeNotification` but they don't get called, when i just add actions to NSUndoManager, so i have to do a first redo or undo action, to get the desired behaviour

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the key was also registering for

`NSUndoManagerCheckpointNotification` "undo manager opens or closes a new undo group"

as this is called when actions are added to the undo manager